# If for loop returns null javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a loop with inner if statements as follows

```
var html = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) 
{
  if(products[i].attrs.product_type == type) 
  {
   html += '<p>hello world</p>';      
  }
}
```

I'd really like to be able to say if no results are returned from for loop, say "Sorry, no results were found" etc… I've tried the following…

```
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) 
{
  if(products[i].attrs.product_type == type) 
  {
   html += '<p>hello world</p>' +i;      
  }
}
```

But that just puts the object number next to the returned result…

Any help would be great as I'm sure this is very easy

Thanks

Comment: at a high level, what you should do is set some variable outside the loop equal to false/zero, then within the loop set it to true/1 and do a check on that variable after the loop is done.  If it's still equal to false/zero, you'll know that nothing met the loop conditions.

Comment: So if the length is zero than output that message..... What does `i` have to do with no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to shotor's answer, but a slightly different approach would be as follows:

```
 var html = "";
 var i;
 var found = false;
 for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) 
{
     if(products[i].attrs.product_type === type) 
   {
     html += '<p>hello world</p>' +i;
     found = true;      
   }
}    

if (found === false)
  {
    //do stuff here.
  }
```

Comment: isTrue=false is a funny var name.

Comment: I'd rename `isTrue` to `found`. Really confusing when you check `isTrue === false`. :)

Comment: adjusted the name.  To me it makes sense, but I suppose it's not the cleanest naming convention in the world :)

Answer (score 2):

At the end check whether the `html` variable is actually filled, if not we didn't find any items and we can use the sorry message:

```
var html = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) 
{
  if(products[i].attrs.product_type === type) 
  {
   html += '<p>hello world</p>';      
  }
}    

if (html === '') { // or: "if (!html)" if you like that sort of thing
  html = 'Sorry, no results were found'
}
```

Also notice that I changed the comparison from `==` to `===`. That's because `==` tries to convert the type. While `===` does not. Use `===` to prevent strange errors, usually that's the one you want. For more info on it: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Updated because of comment by @ASDFGerte

Comment: Your code appears to be checking whether `products` has zero length, not whether the loop has any results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "";
var i;
var hasResult = false;
for ( i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ) 
{
  if( products[i].attrs.product_type == type ) 
  {
        html += '<p>hello world</p>';
        hasResult = true;
  }
}

if( !hasResult ){

    html = "No match";
}
```